# No route found for "GET /portfolio

Tags: php, symfony

I am creating a very basic static page in symfony2 but I am getting no route found error and i already defined the route for my page.

My controller

```
#src/IDP/IDPBundle/Controller/PortfolioController.php
<?php
  namespace IDP\IDPBundle\Controller;
  use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
  class PortfolioController extends Controller
  {
   public function indexAction()
   {
    return $this->render('IDPIDPBundle:Portfolio:index.twig');
   }
  }
```

My routing.yml file

```
#src/IDP/IDPBundle/resources/config/routing.yml
IDPIDPBundle_portfolio:
pattern:  /portfolio
defaults: { _controller: IDPIDPBundle:Portfolio:index }
requirements:
    _method:  GET
```

My routing file in app

```
#app/config/routing.yml
IDPIDPBundle:
resource: "@IDPIDPBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
prefix:   /

# Internal routing configuration to handle ESI
#_internal:
#   resource: "@FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/routing/internal.xml"
#   prefix:   /_internal
```

and when I try this url in the browser the symfony welcome page comes

```
 http://project.dev/app_dev.php/
```

but when I try

```
http://project.dev/app_dev.php/portfolio
```

it give no route found error

What I m doing wrong here ?

any ideas please ?

Comment: Have you run the routing debugger? What do you get from running `php app/console router:debug --env=dev`?

Comment: I copied your code into a new symfony2 project and it works for, the only difference being the formatting of the yaml configuration for the two `routing.yaml` files. is the intendation correct?

Comment: Thanks for the replies it was just because of the Eclipse IDE, the changes were only taking place in the workspace of IDE not on my project root directory. i started using Netbeans my favorite IDE :)

Comment: Fix your indentation. Yaml is very sensitive in this matter.

Comment: hai.... did you put the name of the twig as index.twig or index.html.twig??/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the changes you made is affected in the root of you project not only in the work space of eclipse. Change your eclipse work space to your project root and then

```
IDPIDPBundle:
 resource: "@IDPIDPBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
 prefix:   /

IDPIDPBundle_portfolio:
 pattern:  /portfolio
 defaults: { _controller: IDPIDPBundle:Portfolio:index }
 requirements:
 _method:  GET
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

I think your code an routing is correct. But entered url is not correct. You are not pointing `web` folder in which `app_dev.php`. May be this is your problem.

instead of this url   http://project.dev/app_dev.php/portfolio try the below url

```
 http://project.dev/web/app_dev.php/portfolio
```

hope `project.dev` is your project folder.

Second thing I noticed that you must really care about the indentation of routing.yml file.

```
IDPIDPBundle:
  resource: "@IDPIDPBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
  prefix:   /

IDPIDPBundle_portfolio:
  pattern:  /portfolio
  defaults: { _controller: IDPIDPBundle:Portfolio:index }
  requirements:
     _method:  GET
```

Hope this helps.